# .hover on my div does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm trying to set up Qtip2 and I got stuck writing my javascript. For some reason my .hover code does nothing (tried to get it to console.log something to see if that was the problem and the console is empty). Can you look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks, snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mouseover').hover(function() {
    console.log("mouseover");
    $('mouseover').each(function() {
      $(this).qtip({
        content: {
          text: $(this).next('div')
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.mouseover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.tooltip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class='mouseover'>Tooltip testin'</div>
  <div class='tooltip'> <b>TOOLTIP</b> 
    <p>testin</p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-213.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='tolltip.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$('mouseover').each(function() {` should be  `$('.mouseover').each(function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but why do you need hover to show tooltip? According to [documentation](http://qtip2.com/guides) it's necessary.

Please see this example : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98g92sc6/)

```
  $('.mouseover').each(function() {
      $(this).qtip({
        content: {
          text: $(this).next('div')
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, must have missinterpreted the documentation. Still haven't gotten it to work on my page, but as long as I can look at the working fiddle I should be able to work it out

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mouseover').hover(function() {
        console.log("mouseover");
        $('.mouseover').each(function() {
            $(this).qtip({
                content: { text: $(this).next('div') }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You missed the dot. Hope this works.

Comment: still does nothing when I go over the div with my mouse, console is empty and tooltip won't show

Comment: yeah it's in the html file, first its jquery, then qtip then my code. I know it's there because before I loaded it, the code produced a reference error and now there's no errors. The console for some reason just stays empty, that's why I think the .hover doesn't trigger

Answer (score 0):

Try like this without using javascript:

```
.tooltip {
  display: none;
}
.mouseover:hover .tooltip{
    display:block;
}
```

Check out this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/mncknja0/

Comment: the point is getting a jqeury plugin called qTip2 to work, and I got stuck on the .hover part. I'm figuring out how to use the plugin so I can implement it on another site later on, so that is why I'm using javascript